# Configurar botão voltar nativo android para outras funções

Tags: javascript

Se eu apertar o botão nativo do android Voltar, ele retorna sempre uma pagina anterior.
quero colocar varias condições neste botão voltar. por exemplo , se eu estiver na pagina Home, e um determinado Container estiver visível, quero que faça isso, senão, faz aquilo.
Alguém teria aqui um modelo em JS para eu introduzir no meu projeto ?

Comment: você quer fazer oque exatamente? elabore um pergunta mais detalhada.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Eu tenho um app criado em HTML e JS e que fica em nuvem. Se eu apertar o botão voltar nativo do Android, volta a página anterior . Mas não quero que volte a página anterior, e sim faça o que eu quiser. Por exemplo vá para uma tela específica ou na mesma tela , abra oi feche um container, uma linha, feche uma HTML e abra outra HTML da mesma scren. Coisas assim